# hashmap, java8, null/empty check

Tags: java, java-8

I have a map as follows:

```
private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
```

This map contains its key value pair as:

**Key** **Value**

`myKey`->   **`value`**

**`value`**->   `Another value`

As shown above, this map would either be empty, or have key value pairs including above key values (`myKey`,`value` and `value` as key to next element).

I want to check if this map:

is empty or not

has `myKey` and `value` and if yes, has **`Another value`**. My code has so many `if` `else` so wanted to avoid with better way to find `Another value`

```
  if (map.isEmpty()) {
        if (map.get(myKey) != null || StringUtils.isNotBlank(map).get(myKey).toString())) {
            String nextKey = map.get(myKey).toString();
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(nextKey) && map.get(nextKey) != null
                    && StringUtils.isNotBlank(map.get(nextKey).toString())) {
                String finalValue = map.get(nextKey).toString();
            }
        }

    } else {
        flag = true; 
    }
```

Comment: I don't get it. `map.isEmpty()` should be enough to check if the Map has values or not

Comment: If map has values, I need to get value of myKey. That value would be key to another element.

Comment: @Jacob are you trying to go over the map until one of the Values is not a key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Map's `containsKey` method to avoid multiple `if`

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    if(map.containsKey(myKey) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(map.get(myKey)) 
                             && map.containsKey(map.get(myKey))) {
        flag=false;
    } else {
        flag=true
    }
```

A more simplified version of above code would be

`flag = StringUtils.isBlank(map.get(myKey)) || !map.containsKey(map.get(myKey));`

Comment: Yes. This is what I am looking for. I don't know why people are so desperate for down vote

Comment: Instead of `if(condition) someVariable = false; else someVariable = true;` you should write `someVariable = ! condition;` everything else is just redundant. Further, since `StringUtils.isNotBlank` tests for `null`, the preceding `containsKey` test is obsolete. So you only need `flag = StringUtils.isBlank(map.get(myKey)) || !map.containsKey(map.get(myKey));`

Comment: @Jacob I suppose, you got a downvote, because you wrote a confusing question. You provided a code example, which is only executed when the map is empty, which makes no sense at all. Not to speak of gems like `StringUtils.isNotBlank(map)`…

Comment: @Holger Very good observation. I have updated my answer and included your version

Answer (score 1):

I guess what your looking for is an ordered list of objects. Why not just keep a list?